# How do you run netscape 2 on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, browser

I've been trying to follow the instructions [here](http://www.jwz.org/blog/2008/03/happy-run-some-old-web-browsers-day/) to get netscape 2 to run on Ubuntu 13.04. I created a file called "netscape2.conf" to /etc/modeprobe.d and put this in it:

```
alias binfmt-0064 binfmt_aout
```

Then I downloaded the [tarball they provided](http://home.mcom.com/archives/netscape-linux-libs.tar.gz) and extracted that in the root directory. Finally [I downladed netscape 2](http://home.mcom.com/archives/) and extracted it. However, when I try to run it as a normal user it just spits out "killed" to the terminal. If I use sudo to run it then it says

```
./netscape: can't find library 'libm.so.4'
```

Ok so I explicitly add the paths to the $PATH variable using export and try again. Same problem. What am I doing wrong? Is it still possible to run this ancient browser on modern Ubuntu?

---

**EDIT**

Ok thanks to Paul I've got past that error message. In /etc/ld.so.conf.d I created a file called netscape2.conf and put the lib directories in it like so:

```
/usr/i486-linuxaout/lib
/usr/i486-linux-libc5/lib
```

I then did `ldconfig` to update the libraries as suggested. The next error was because XkeysymDB wasn't found. It told me to fix this I just had to set the $XKEYSYMDB variable, which I did. Now the next error is:

```
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-helvetica-bold-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Warning: Cannot convert string "-*-courier-medium-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-iso8859-*" to type FontStruct
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This sounds like I don't have the right fonts installed. So does anyone know what the right fonts, where I can get them and how to install them?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to use a browser which is pre-history?

Comment: Why not go with Netscape 4.0 instead of 2?

Comment: @ToDo Curiosity.

Comment: @Alvar netscape 2 had the first release version of javascript.

Comment: hmm, cool, (: ..

Comment: try with a virtual machine of like Ubuntu 8.04 or such maybe it will be easier...

Comment: Ahh good idea, that might save me a lot of headaches. It would be cool to have it run on natively on modern ubuntu though.

Comment: @Alvar, in fact if you put that as answer I'll accept it if I don't get netscape working on 13.04. It does work on 7.10.

Comment: How did you fix the "bash: /netscape: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error" problem?

Answer (score 2):

It's not finding the libraries from the tarball. Try `sudo ldconfig` to refresh the library cache.

(In general, it's not safe to unpack random tarballs from the internet in your root directory. In this case, JWZ is very experienced and his blog post says that he tested it, so it will probably be fine, but be very careful about doing this in the future.)

Comment: Thanks Paul, I got past that error message now. I've edited my question with the next error I'm stuck on.